# how to export arraycollection to .xml file to my local machine

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

How can I export my arraycollection to .xml file and save it on the hard disk? because presently i could be able to convert from arraycollection to xml object but I am unable to save it as .xml file physically. please somebody help me in this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the FileReference class.  You won't be able to do save it locally without user interaction, though.

Comment: If i use file reference, i ll get a prompt of save as, is that possible to save directly without any prompt of where to save and how to save?

Comment: if you don't want the user to know/deal with the file save prompt why not use SQLlite for persistence http://www.flex-blog.com/adobe-air-sqlite-example/

Comment: @sam In a browser based app; you cannot save files to the user's computer without their interaction.  In an AIR app you can use the File class. Mark's suggestion to use SQLLite would also only work in an AIR app.  If you have a small amount of data; you may be able to use a shared object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Flash Player, your only choice is to use the FileReference class. With it's method `save()` it's possible to open a native dialog window that allows you to save the file locally.

If you are using Adobe Air, it's possible to use either FileReference class or File class to save the desired data. While FileReference works the same as in Flash Player, the File class has extended methods, it allows to both read and save files by starting a file stream and it does not require user interaction.

Here's are quick snippets for both classes:

**FileReference**:

```
var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
fr.save(yourData, "filename.extension");

private function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    // do something when file is saved
}
```

**File**:

```
var f:File = new File(path);
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(fileWriter, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes(xmlData); // you can use writeBytes() for binary data
fileStream.close();
```

You can find plenty tutorials that explain more about using these classes on the internet if you wish to study more about them.

Comment: Thanks, this might helpful for me.

Comment: Just stringify the XML and write it to a cookie.